# Meaning for a matrix to be diagonalizable over one field but not over another.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Here is the question I am trying to solve:

Show that the matrix
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0
\end{pmatrix}

is diagonalizable over the field of complex numbers, but not over the field of real numbers.

I am wondering what does it mean in  my calculations to show that a matrix is diagonalizable over the field of complex numbers, but not over the field of real numbers? does it only means that I have complex eigenvalues or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linear transformation $\Bbb R^4\to\Bbb R^4$ which, given some basis, is represented by your matrix will not be diagonalizable. It does not have four eigenvalues from the scalar field (even counted with multiplicity), which means it doesn't yield the full basis of eigenvectors that a diagonalization requires.

The linear transformation $\Bbb C^4\to \Bbb C^4$ which, given some basis, is represented by your matrix will be diagonalizable. It has four distinct eigenvalues from the scalar field, each with a corresponding 1-dimensional eigenspace, which lets us create a full basis of eigenvectors.

Comment: A simpler illustration of the same phenomenon is $$\begin{pmatrix}0&-1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: Sorry if this is a trivial question, how do we know that we have a full basis of eigenvectors or no?

Comment: @Brain For a linear transformation $F^n\to F^n$ over a field $F$, the characteristic polynomial has degree $n$. Each root of the characteristic polynomial yields an eigenvalue. The dimension of the corresponding eigenspace is _at most_ equal to the multiplicity of the corresponding root. In the real case, we only get two roots and both of multiplicity 1, so the corresponding eigenspaces each have dimension (at most) 1. That's not enough to span $\Bbb R^4$. In the complex case we get 4 distinct roots, so four distinct eigenspaces, which clearly is enough to span $\Bbb C^4$.

Comment: It is when you have a characteristic polynomial that can be completely factored into linear factors, but some of them are repeated (which doesn't happen here) that things get interesting and the theory gets deeper.